# How prove $ \; |f(1)|\le 2004\;$ if $\sqrt {x(1 - x)}\; \Big|f(x)\Big|\le 334$ for $f(x) = Ax^2+ Bx + C $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $ \; A,B, C\in {\mathbb R} ,\;$ and  $ \; f(x) = Ax^2+ Bx + C$ and

$ \sqrt {x(1 - x)} \left|f(x)\right|\le 334,\;\forall x\in [0,1]\;$.

How prove  $ \; \left|f(1)\right|\le 2004\;$ ?

Comment: so substitute $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{10}$ to get bounds then express $A+B+C$ as a linear combination of the expessions you have bounded.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I tried your solution but the coefficients of $x^2$ are distinct of the $x$ and the linear combination how can be performed?

Comment: You get three vectors, it is as if you have multiplied $(A,B,C)$ by a vandermond matrix. Since that matrix is invertible the vectors are independent. So now express $A+B+C$ as a linear combination and use the triangle inequality. I have not preformed the calculation so I dont know what number you get, but it seems to me to be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Actually the numbers $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{4}{5}$ might be an even better choice.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus So that yields the set of inequalities: $|A/4+B/2+C|\le 668, |A/25+B/5+C|\le 835, |16A/25 + 4B/5+C|\le 835$. A linear combination would be $D|A/4+B/2+C|+E|A/25+B/5+C|+F|16A/25 + 4B/5+C|\le 668D+835E+835F$. How do we start solving for $D,E,F$?

Comment: Yeah so now its just a problem in linear algebra, you can write down three equations for D,E and F and solve them.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus But they don't distribute into the absolute value unless we restrict them to being positive? Or am I way off? And if we try to use the triangle inequality, don't we lose the fact that they're less than $668,835,835$ respectively?

Comment: No, forget the absolute values you want $A+B+C=D(A/4+$ etc. Once you have this you will use the triangle inequality.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I get $D=-16/9, E=5/9, F=20/9$. Can you show the triangle inequality step? I still see it backwards.

Comment: Well now we say $16/9(668)+5/9(835)+20/9(535)=3507$ which unfortunately is too large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will make the linear transformation: $x = \frac{1-t}{2}$ for $t \in [-1,1]$,and $g(t) = \frac{f\left(\frac{1-t}{2}\right)}{668}$ to rewrite the problem as: $$\sqrt{1-t^2}|g(t)| \le 1 \textrm{ for }t \in [-1,1] \tag{1}$$

and make the more general statement that, for any polynomial $g$ with degree $n-1$, satisfying $(1)$, then: $$|g(t)| \le n \textrm{ for } t \in [-1,1] \tag{*}$$

We use the [Lagrange Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) on the [Chebyshev points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes), $t_j = \cos\frac{(2j-1)\pi}{2n}$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,n$ the roots of the $n^{th}$ [Chebyshev Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials): $T_n(t)$, to obtain the identity:

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\sqrt{1-t_i^2}g(t_i)\frac{T_n(t)}{t-t_i} \tag{2}$$

Take $t \in [-1,1]$ and if $t \in [t_n,t_1]$, that is $[-t_1,t_1]$, then from $(1)$:

$$|g(t)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t_1^2}} = \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{2n}} \le n$$

by the [Jordan Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_inequality).

If, $t > t_1$ (similarly for $t < -t_1$), the triangle inequality on $(2)$ gives

$$|g(t)| \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{T_n(t)}{t-t_i} = \frac{T'_n(t)}{n}$$

Since, $T_n(\cos \theta) = \cos n\theta \implies T_n'(\cos \theta) = n\frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin \theta}$ but, $|\sin n\theta| \le n|\sin \theta|$

Therefore, $|T_n'(\cos \theta)| \le n^2 \implies |g(t)| \le n$ for $t > t_1$ (or $t < -t_1$) as well.

Equality holds in $(*)$ when $g(t) = \pm U_{n-1}(t)$, ($U_{n}$ being the [Chebyshev Polynomial of $2^{nd}$ kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Relation_between_Chebyshev_polynomials_of_the_first_and_second_kinds) ) at $t=\pm 1$.

Since, $f$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, we have: $$|f(x)| \le 3 \times 688 = 2004 \textrm{ for } x \in [0,1]$$ and equality holds when $f(x) = 688(4(1-2x)^2 -1)$, at $x = 1$.

Comment: For which A,B,C is $|f(1)|=2004$?

Comment: @piteer equality holds when $g(t) = U_{n-1}(t)$, the [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Relation_between_Chebyshev_polynomials_of_the_first_and_second_kinds). So, in this case equality holds for $f(x) = 688 U_2(1-2x) = 688(4(1-2x)^2 - 1)$.